# How check value viewable types

Tags: scala, polymorphism, match

I have something like this:

```
def my_check[T](arg: T) = arg match {
  case x: GenTraversable[_] = ...  // XX
  case x: Array[_]
   ...
```

I want to merge some `cases` expression:
In the code above marked with XX, I want to check if `arg <: GenTraversable[_]` or `arg <% GenTraversable[-]`. For example, the `Array` type could match this case as well (there exists implicit conversion from `Array` to `WrapperArray <: GenTraversable`)

I don't want to use exception in the solution, so I'm not interesting in something like:

```
try:
  val trv: GenTraversable = arg
catch ...
```

I've tried in `my_check` function  something like

```
T <:< GenTraversable        // error: not found: value T
```

But compiler complain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implicit resolution (<% included) is a compile time thing, based on the types as they are known at compile time.

In your routine, the only thing that is known at compile time about arg is that it is of type `T`, which is about nothing. You might have something such as

```
def check[T <% GenTraversable[_](arg: T) = ...
```

This is definitely not the same thing however your routine could only be called if `arg` is known at compile time to be a `GenTraversable`.

I don't know where you wrote `T <:< GenTraversable[_]` (probably in a place where a value is expected). To get the implicit conversion from types `A` to `B`, you can write `implicitly[A => B]`, but again, it will fail if it cannot be resolved at compile time. So it would not be any help here, with `T` an unconstrained generic parameter.

Comment: I've tried to write `T <:< GenTraversable[_]` in the more general case: `case x: AnyRef`.
Is it possible to use it with generic type `T`?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure I understand your question. This code works for me:

```
class X[T] (name: T)

class Y[T] (_name: T, age: Int) extends X[T](_name)

def foo[T](arg: T) = arg match {
  case a: Y[_] => println("y " )
  case a: X[_] => println("x " )
  case _ => println("?")
}

val y = new Y("Olle", 3);
foo(y)
```

If Y is a subclass of X (as in this case) then you must start with Y and take the more generic classes later on. Please explain the question once more...?

Comment: No, try with Y not extending X, but has implicit conversion to X. And I want to have X and Y in the same case, or make more general case, where I can check if argument type is T <: X or T <% X

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure this isn't possible. Pattern matching happens at runtime, and distinction between implicits and non-implicits only exists at complile-time.